# Alter database dynamically passing values in a loop in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I want to dynamically use `c` in this for loop and rename.
I tried these two below, but that didn't work.

```
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (select name from v$tempfile)
    LOOP
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[alter database rename file c to '/tmp/temp03.dbf']';

    END LOOP;
END;
```

```
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (select name from v$tempfile)
    LOOP
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[alter database rename file  '(|| c.name || )' to '/tmp/temp03.dbf']';

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: format your question so we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you are missing some {} in there see http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_execute_immediate.htm for more information... but basically should be q{' at the start of the string and }' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I didn´t check the alter database sintax but i think the rigth code is:

```
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (select name from v$tempfile)
    LOOP
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter database rename file  '''|| c.name || ''' to ''/tmp/temp03.dbf''';

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Note you have to escape quotes with double quotes

Comment: The OP's code uses `q'[ ... ]'` . This is a legal alternative to explicitly escaping individual quotes in strings.